# Knockout validation - to match starts with specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex, knockout-validation

I have to validate if an ID starts with a specific set of characters, followed by alphanumeric values. I am using knockout validation.

I have the code here,

```
var value_id = ko.observable('').extend({
            minLength: 18,
            maxLength: 18,
            pattern: {
              params: '/^(xyz34|xyz12)((?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])){13}/g',
              message: 'Please provide a valid ID.'
            },
            required: {
              message: 'Please enter a ID.',
              params: true
            }
          });
```

The same pattern is working fine in online regex tester.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Try it without the single quotes `params: /^(xyz34|xyz12)((?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])){13}/g,` What are the exact rules for the pattern? The `{13}` repeat a capturing group with 2 lookaheads. Did you mean a total of 18 chars where after matching xyz34 or xyz12 there should be at least a char a-zA-Z and a digit? `^(?=.{18}$)xyz(?:12|34)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` https://regex101.com/r/xVUFUB/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes removing the single quotes is working fine.